# AngularJS - ngRoute otherwise not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have the below javascript code.

```
App.config(['$provide', '$routeProvider', function($provide, $routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html'
    })
    .when('/404', {
        templateUrl: '404.html'
    })
    .when('/500', {
        templateUrl: '500.html'
    })
    .when('/:pages', {
        templateUrl: function(routeParams) {
            return 'views/' + routeParams.pages + '.html';
        }
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/404'
    })

}]);
```

Everything working fine as per the condition specified.

But if I enter some fake URL's. I get a error in the console log that the specified URL is not found.

Is there any mistake I'm doing with the otherwise here?

Please help me out and do let me know why the `otherwise` what I've specified doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check if it isn't using the `'/:pages'` case? (Place a `console.log()` before `return 'views/'...`)

Comment: I get the URL as `views/fakeurl.html`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.when('page/:pages', {
    templateUrl: function(routeParams) {
        return 'views/' + routeParams.pages + '.html';
    }
})...
```

change `when` url like this ?

Comment: its pleasure to help you. if u try a url that want to goes with otherwise thats will not go with it instead it goes with .when('/:pages', { .. this route that is the case. :). please mark as the correct answer if u get the results. thanks :)

Comment: because `/fakeurl`, `/anotherurl` `/andanotherurl` all of these urls compatible with ` .when('/:pages',..` this route right ? so yes these otherwise routes are always goes with that one :)

Comment: It's routing all my clicks to 404

Comment: do u load the 404 route when there is a HTTP 404 error ?

Comment: Yes.. but which doesn't work in my method. And with the solution you've provided all the clicks are getting routed to the 404 page.

Comment: did u check that u have template files for the routes ?

Comment: can please create a jsfiddle or plunker ? :)